# Making query params optional in IBM API Connect

Tags: apiconnect

Hi we are using IBM Api Connect as a gateway for our api's, i am unable to figure out how to make query params optional, i tried doing it in the DESIGN and ASSEMBLE sections  of IBM api connect, but no luck.

this is my final URL that i want to invoke
                                                            www.testdomain.products/getProducts?param1 = " "& param2 = " " & param3 = " "

here all the params are optional  i am giving this url as

www.testdomain.products/getProducts?param1=$(request.parameters.param1)&param2=$(request.parameters.param2) & param3=$(request.parameters.param3)

in one use case i am only passing param1, and want the final url to be constructed only with param1 but this is what i am seeing

www.testdomain.products/getProducts?param1="value"&param2=&param3=

what should i do so that the url is constructed with only the values that i am passing, like this

www.testdomain.products/getProducts?param1="value"

Comment: Does this have anything to do with IBM MQ?

Comment: When you say you had no luck, what does that mean? You invoked the API, but it complained about missing query parameters? Or what?

Comment: Hi Matt, sorry  i was not clear with my question, i have updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just want to proxy the query string? In which case you can use $(target-url)$(request.search) as your invoke URL.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by creating the **dynamic target URL** using a script rather than setting static backend service URLin invoke/Proxy action.

**Assembly section**

Get ***GatewayScript Action*** before invoke

```
var targetUrl = "www.testdomain.products/getProducts?";
var input_param1 = apim.getvariable('request.parameters.param1');
var input_param2 = apim.getvariable('request.parameters.param2');


if(input_param1 !==null || input_param1 !="" || input_param1 != undefined ){
    targetUrl = targetUrl.concat("param1="+input_param1))
}
if(input_param2 !==null || input_param2 !="" || input_param2 != undefined ){
    if(targetUrl.indexOf('param1') > 0){
        targetUrl = targetUrl.concat('&')
    }
    targetUrl = targetUrl.concat("param2="+input_param2))
}

apim.setvariable('target-url',targetUrl)
```

In Invoke/Proxy - Use this `$(target-url)`

There might be some syntax issue, but we can achieve using the above way. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Srikanth.. thankyou.. the solution that i implemented was  by appending  $(request.querystring) to my url like -- this www.testdomain.products/getProducts?$(request.querystring) in INVOKE , all parameters configured for the path in the design section  are optional

Comment: If it is working fine, then no worries. else you can follow the above approach. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Srikanth i have another question.. i posted in another thread                                                https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53539822/parsing-xml-response-in-gatewayscript   ..

Comment: Hi Vinay, Shared some answer found from IBM community hope that will help you. Upvote the answer if it was helpful to you

Comment: But this will not work if you try to test it in the IBM dev-portal. The "Try It" option will not let you specify any query string.