# Parsing XML Response In GateWayScript

Tags: apiconnect

Hi i am new to API connect ... i have a use case where i have to merge responses coming from two endpoints in XML format based on certain conditions.

My flow in the assemble section is like this

1) **INVOKE**

(i make my 
first service call
and capture the response
in a custom '*Response
object varibale*' -XMLResponse1

2) **INVOKE**

(i make my 
second service call
and here i am not using any 
custom '*Response object varibale*'
Instead i am using apim.getvaribale('message.body') to get the response

3)**GATEWAYSCRIPT**

Here i want to write my script for parsing the xml and merging the two responses
and send back the merged response to the consumer

I observed that  the xml response is not getting captured in a  custom Response object variable when i try to capture it like below

var test1= apim.getvariable('XMLResponse1');
test1.item(0).childNodes

it throws me an exception like this

**test1.item is not a function**

now for the second response like below where i am not capturing the response  in a custom Response object variable it works well

var test2= apim.getvariable('message.body');

**My question:**

1)How do i capture the xml responses in a custom Response object variable?

2)How can i parse the response into a javascript object? are there any libraries supported in api connect?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the samples found from IBM community. Hope this may help you.

```
**** Sample XML ****

 <Routing>        
    <partner name="Partner A" key="1">
        <from_ID>PartnerA-KEY1-INT</from_ID>
        <to_ID>PartnerA-KEY1-EXT</to_ID>
        <destination>PartnerA-KEY1-DESTINATION</destination>
    </partner>  
    <partner name="Partner B" key="2">
        <from_ID>PartnerB-KEY2-INT</from_ID>
        <to_ID>PartnerB-KEY2-EXT</to_ID>
        <destination>PartnerB-KEY2-DESTINATION</destination>
    </partner>
    <partner name="Partner C" key="3">
        <from_ID>PartnerC-KEY3-INT</from_ID>
        <to_ID>PartnerC-KEY3-EXT</to_ID>
        <destination>PartnerC-KEY3-DESTINATION</destination>
    </partner>  
</Routing>

 **** Corresponing Gateway Script *****

var response = apim.getvariable('XMLResponse1.body');
var objType = response.item(0);
var string  = objType.getElementsByTagName("partner").item(0).getElementsByTagName("from_ID").item(0).textContent;
```

> output --->  string = PartnerA-KEY1-INT

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to merge them in a GatewayScript node??

You could merge them in a mapping node, in wich you have 2 variables as input (refered to the output objects of your invokes)  and one XML object as output...

If you have to apply some conditions or comparisons, you could do them in the code part of the mapping nodes

[image: Mapping Node Comparison]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.